# не могу создать проект в vs 2022

Tags: visual-studio

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже пробовал скачать все версии .NET Framework Target Packs и со словом Framework, и переустанавливал весь vs2022